# PHP Loop and and exist Request

Tags: php, while-loop, sleep

I am just asking if this is possible in php.

I need to loop through till some conditions is true . But Return the response.

I want loop to continue in background .

here is my code

if possible how can I achieve  this

```
function load(){
    $loop = true;
    while($loop){
        sleep(180);
        $sql = "SELECT * from table_test id = 1";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->row();
        if($row['status'] == 2){
            $loop = false
        }
    }
    $response['status'] = 'ok';
    return $response;
}
```

I want the While Loop to run in background.

How can achieve this?

Is it possible without using cron job.

Comment: If the loop runs in the background, how will you return a response? The rest of the script will continue running.

Comment: I want to know how can I achieve  that is the issue I am facing now.

Comment: So by "in the background", you mean you want this to continually run on the server, not related to a user's web session. Is that correct?

Comment: it keeps loading until the condition returns true.

Comment: @Brandon yes I need run it in the server.

Comment: That's not "in the background" if the client is waiting for the response. You just want to prevent the web request from timing out?

Comment: Use `set_time_limit()` to increase the maximum execution time.

Comment: @Barmar yes it is not in the background. I need to change the code. I am looking solution

Comment: @Barmar No is it possible to trigger a command  or run a curl forget without waiting return a response

Comment: @BLPraveen you can execute a job in the background by using proc_open and shell_exec.